# django admin encoding error when adding new item

Tags: django, encoding, admin

Please, I am a new user of django and I don't understand what is wrong in my model.
I have activated the admin, and created a new model:

```
class Strumenti(models.Model):
    cod_stru = models.AutoField(db_column='cod_stru', primary_key=True)
    sht_name = models.CharField(db_column='sht_name', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    descr = models.CharField(db_column='descr', max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    isin = models.CharField(db_column='isin', max_length=16)
    tipo = models.CharField(db_column='tipo', max_length=1)
    mktcode = models.ForeignKey(Mercati, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    ccy1 = models.ForeignKey(Valute, related_name='ccyone', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ccy2 = models.ForeignKey(Valute, related_name='ccytwo', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    beta = models.DecimalField(db_column='beta', max_digits=2, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    system = models.NullBooleanField(db_column='system', default=False, null=True)
    template = models.NullBooleanField(db_column='template', default=False, null=True)
    tenor = models.CharField(db_column='tenor', max_length=4, blank=True, null=True)
    divy = models.DecimalField(db_column='divy', max_digits=5, decimal_places=5, blank=True, null=True)
    fxpair = models.CharField(db_column='fxpair', max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
    cod_emitt = models.ForeignKey(Emittenti, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    idx_code = models.ForeignKey(Indexdef, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    vol_type = models.IntegerField(db_column='vol_type', blank=True, null=True)

def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s - %s - %s - %s' % (self.cod_stru, self.sht_name, self.descr, self.tipo)
```

when I try to ADD a new record I get this error:

```
**'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe3' in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)**
```

I am using Django 1.9, python 2.7, Mysql (utf8_unicode_ci)

hereunder the error during template rendering

```
In template /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html, error at line 33
ascii
23  {% endblock %}
24  {% endif %}
25  
26  {% block content %}<div id="content-main">
27  {% block object-tools %}
28  {% if change %}{% if not is_popup %}
29    <ul class="object-tools">
30      {% block object-tools-items %}
31      <li>
32          {% url opts|admin_urlname:'history' original.pk|admin_urlquote as history_url %}
33          <a href="{% add_preserved_filters history_url %}" class="historylink">{% trans "History" %}</a>
```

someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem.
I stored in the 'Valute' table the description "São Tomé and Príncipe".

chars like ã é í produce the error, even if I don't understand why my .encode(uft-8) didn't work...
Any why I have just changed the string to "Sao Tome and Principe" and now it seems to be fine.